# TeamCity Automatic Merge Not Working after Octopus Deploy step

Tags: teamcity

Teamcity automerge on build success not working, from 'master' to 'hotfix' branch

All our projects have  'master' and a 'hotfix' branch. Normally we build, deploy, run all our tests and finally deploy to PROD from 'master'.  All our Deploys are done via Octopus. What we want to do is ensure 'master' is merged into 'hotfix' branch after every successful Octopus Deploy to PROD.

But I cannot get it to work. I have experimented with various configurations, and the final one is summarised below with [screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i04DF.jpg).

1. Step 'Promote PROD' -  Attach VCS roots for both 'services_itemlabelling'and 'services_itemlabelling_automerge'.

   - The former points to the 'master' branch and is the one that triggers the actual build
   - I have also tried removing this VCS root and having only 'services_itemlabelling_automerge', but same behaviour
   - The latter points to the 'hotfix' branch and is used ONLY in 'Promote PROD' step
2. Step 'Promote PROD' - Create automatic merge build feature to set the branch to watch (+:master) and the one to merge into (hotfix OR +:hotfix)
3. Step 'Promote PROD' - OctopusDeploy:PromoteRelease step

The build succeeds and I can see the checkouts occur - on BOTH VCS roots - without errors, but there is no merge carried out as confirmed by looking in our Git repos.

Also, I have looked in the'teamcity-vcs.log' file, but not found any entries apart from those relating to the VCS checkout.

Based on the [TC instructions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Automatic+Merge) it seems this should be straightforward, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end. The trick is in understanding the difference between default branch and branch specification.

Lots of people seem to be having problems with TC automerge setups, so here is the [complete answer](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207123175-Automatic-merges-of-feature-branches?page=1#community_comment_360000424899) I posted on the TeamCity community forum.